# Javascript: run object method on DOM object selected through other property

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, properties, prototype

I am very new to javascript.

Here I am failing to run an object method on a DOM element that I selected through another property of the same object. I suspect there is something wrong with my thinking!

Thanks in advance for any piece of help.

```
var Arrow = function() {
    this.current = $('.arrow');
    this.previous = null;
    this.bend = function() {
        // do bend
    };
};

var arrow = new Arrow();

arrow.current.bend();
```

Comment: `$('.arrow');` possibly selects multiple elements (all with class `arrow`). You add the function `bend` to `Arrow`, but try to call it on what's in `arrow.current`.

Comment: `arrow.bend();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bend() is a method of Arrow, not current. Use arrow.bend() and it will also have access to current using this.current.

Answer (score 1):

arrow.current.bend is not defined.

You have defined:

- this.current as the Array of DOM elements.
- this.bend as method with a function.

Hence, you can call:

- arrow.current >> returns Array of DOMs
- arrow.bend() >> executes function bend.
- arrow.current.bend() does not exist.

Also, note that arrow.current is an array. You'd first need to get each of the elements:

```
for (element of arrow.current) { element.bend(); }
```

However, as said before, element does not have a bend element by default and you have not appended at any point. Only arrow has a bend property.

I hope this guides you on why this does not work.
However, if you want to open a question on what you are trying to achieve, maybe we can help to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `bend()` on `arrow` object. In `bend()` function, you do what you need to do.

```
var Arrow = function() {
    this.current = $('.arrow');
    this.previous = null;
    this.bend = function() {
        // do bend
        current.style = 'bent';
    };
};

var arrow = new Arrow();
arrow.bend();
```

Answer (score 1):

So two things.

You called the right method on the wrong object

```
arrow.bend(); // not arrow.current.bend()
```

The second possible problem is with `this.current = $('.arrow');`. To get the an element from the `DOM`, you should make sure it's totally loaded. I'd suggest the following

```js
    var Arrow = function($arrow) {
        this.current = $arrow;
        this.previous = null;
    };

    // To avoid creating the `bend` in every instance of Arrow
    Arrow.prototype.bend = function() {
            console.log(this.current.attr('id'));
        };
    
    $(function () {
        // Now it's certain that the DOM is completely loaded
        var arrow = new Arrow($('.arrow').first());
    
        arrow.bend();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow" id="toto">arrow<div>
```